# Reopen review thinks I completed a review if I performed the action prior to seeing the review

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

I voted to reopen a question then went looking for the review to see if others agree... According to the votes tab on my profile I voted to reopen at 19:25 UTC today:

[image]

But, according to the review I voted to reopen at 19:50, 25 minutes later.

[image]

I have not voted to reopen this question; the time is exactly the same time as Nirk performed the reopen review and the *Review completed* seems to assume that I have reviewed this.

If I view a reopen review page and I've already completed the action that precludes me from performing that review then it looks like the data for me is being faked as if I were the first person to perform the review. It's already known that I cannot review the post as I'm not allowed to perform a review; so, it would be better to tell me this, à la the close votes queue.

Comment: There are two problems here, but before I get into explaining the first one... I'm *pretty certain* you're not even looking at the right review.

Comment: It's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3275376) @Shog9... still unsure about whether the reopen vote was the right thing but it's not an appalling question (might have some other merits) and at least it's not I have the answer handed to me on a plate by the traceback...

Comment: Ah, so that's supposed to be an underline and not a really poorly hand-drawn arrow. My mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Review completed" just means that the review was completed. By *people.* Not necessarily by *you*. With over 10K on SO, you can easily view *anyone's* completed reviews, and they'll all look the same way - some of them just won't have your name on them anywhere.

With that out of the way, this is what happened:

1. You viewed [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756930/can-data-in-a-text-file-be-called-a-database), left a comment, and voted to reopen (with the vote logged at 2013-11-03 19:25:39Z)
2. The review queue detected your vote at 2013-11-03 19:43:10Z and added a review task for that question.
3. By 2013-11-03 19:50:11Z, 3 "Leave Closed" votes had been logged and the review task was marked "Completed."

Note that even if you'd gotten to it in time, the system would've prevented you from reviewing this particular question in the reopen queue (since you wouldn't have been able to vote to reopen).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than whatever I was conjuring up in my head; thanks! and stop slagging off my extremely good freehand underline :-)!